# Custom Ubuntu Core images purpose or benefit?

Tags: git, ubuntu-core, core-apps

I followed this tutorial on how to make a custom image:
https://snapcraft.io/tutorials/create-your-own-core-20-image#1-overview

Is the purpose of making a custom image just to include custom snaps? Is the primary benefit that it saves you having to install snaps after installing the default core image?

If one wanted to git clone some files into position, and modify a few other things on the system (say config files and settings), I am guessing one can't do that with a custom core image?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too broad

Comment: Ubuntu Core is intended to be a platform for *devices* to use, not necessarily for humans to use directly (though a stock install does have a fully-featured shell that can be used by humans). A custom image permits a developer to add features that the device will use, to remove features that the device won't use, and to lock down features that may be misused or present a security threat. Ubuntu Core is secure by default and can be used for a kiosk, perhaps without need for customization: See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/secure-ubuntu-kiosk for an example.

Comment: Thank you @user535733, that gives me some great context to understanding this stuff.